# Extjs EmptyText Allignment to the right

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

Can you please take a look at this form panel:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/xuCQN/2/`
```

in the email textfield, I wanted the emptytext to be on the right, but what happened is when i focus on the field it get back to the left! How can i force it to stay on the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to do that you have to use `input:focus` property of css.
**And here is the fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/xuCQN/3/